How can I make sure all my links in my SPA keep the user within my SPA?
I recently started working on my first SPA. There's some basic JavaScript and php on it right now. Anyway, the biggest issue I'm having right now, is how can I put links inside my SPA without them sending me into an entirely new page and basically ruining the whole purpose of making my website an app. Here is my code. I will explain more after.
index.php
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php include './includes/header.php'; ?>

        <div id="main-content">
            <!-- Content will be loaded here dynamically -->
        </div>

        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
                // Function to load content into the main-content div
                const loadContent = (page) => {
                    fetch(page)
                        .then(response => {
                            if (!response.ok) {
                                throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
                            }
                            return response.text();
                        })
                        .then(data => {
                            document.getElementById('main-content').innerHTML = data;
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.error('There has been a problem with your fetch operation:', error);
                            document.getElementById('main-content').innerHTML = '<p>Error loading page</p>';
                        });
                };

                // Load the default page
                loadContent('./pages/home.php');

                // Handle navigation click
                document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link').forEach(link => {
                    link.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        const page = e.target.getAttribute('data-page');
                        if (page) {
                            loadContent(page);
                        } else {
                            console.error('The data-page attribute is missing on the clicked link.');
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>

    </body>

</html>


header.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
            <title>Jethro Blemur</title>
            <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
            <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
            <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Sevillana&family=Tangerine:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/style.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            
            <style>
                #navbar{
                    position: fixed;
                    top: 1vh;
                    right: 1%;
                    width: 15%; 
                    padding: .5% .1%;
                    box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px 1px black;
                    text-align: center;
                    border-radius: 20px;
                    background-color: white;
                }
                #navbar a {
                    font-size: 40px;
                    margin: 1%;
                    text-decoration: none;
                    color: turquoise;
                    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
                    transition: color .5s ease;
                }
                #navbar a:visited{
                    color: turquoise;
                    text-shadow: 2px 2px 4px #000000;
                }
                #navbar a:hover{
                    color:white;
                    background-color: aqua;
                }
                #navbar a:active,
                #navbar a.active{
                    border-bottom: 3px solid white;
                    transition: border-bottom .5s ease;
                }
                #navbar a:active:hover,
                #navbar a.active:hover {
                    border-bottom: 3px solid turquoise;
                }
            </style>
        </head>

        <body>
            <nav id="navbar">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link" data-page="./pages/home.php">Home</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-link" data-page="./pages/projects.php">Projects</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-link" data-page="./pages/about.php">About</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav-link" data-page="./pages/contact.php">Contact</a>
            </nav>
        </body>

</html>

about.php
<?php $currentPage = 'about'?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/style.css">
<head>
    <title>About me</title>
</head>
<body id="sboutpage">
    <div id="container">
        <h2>About Me</h2>
        <p>
            Some text for now
        </p>
    </div>
</body>

Basically, using my navbar (the contents are in the header.php code) the app works like it should. It just displays the new portion of the app without making me navigate to a new page. However, when I click on one of my quicklinks, it makes me navigate to a new page in other words, it makes me leave the app, which is not what I want. What do I do to make it so that whenever I click on any link in the website, it keeps me in the app? Feel free to ask me any questions if I was not clear enough!
Chatgpt was not very helpful it basically told me to just combined all my pages into one, which defeats the purpose of an app. It would make my code a bit harder to read. Better to have a file for every page.

My first thought is to detect all pages links, and then filter based on what you consider to be “your site”, then block the default click and fetch. Also add a MutationObserver to your main element that you are swapping content on, and rescan on change. Or just rescan whenever you manually change, I guess. Maybe add an attribute to links that are already wired so they don’t get re-wired.

Hopefully every one of your URLs is a valid way to enter your SPA still? So if I, a person who often opens links in new windows (and generally hates most SPAs) does this, the site still works? Same with SEO, btw. You want me to go down a certain path, but if I take another path (which has been the default path for decades), things still work. From your perspective, slower, but that’s my problem, not yours.

@ChrisHaas I actually never thought of when people type in certain url. As far as I know it always sends users to my home page. Like when you refresh it’ll send you right back to the homepage. I actually don’t know how to change that, I’m pretty new to JavaScript

@ChrisHaas just tested, if I put in a url manually, for instance to my about.php file, it’ll send me to a new page that is not a part of my SPA.

Like I said, I really don’t like SPAs, and I’ve even built them sometimes. But maybe I’m just old. My recommendation/stance is the JS should be used to enhance an experience, but the default experience should still work. If you don’t want the default experience (an HTTP GET request), then just switch to buttons with attributes. That’s my two cents.

@ChrisHaas Your “two cents” was worth 1000 dollars to me. I appreciate the time you took to leave your comments. They gave me a lot to think about. Thank you. You said that you dislike SPA’s so I wonder, I would like to keep my website as an app of some form where the entire site will be loaded at once (it’ll be small so it shouldn’t be too hefty for any server) what would you recommend me do instead of making it an SPA? Apologies if my comment makes no sense.

If your site is truly small enough, one option is to just use PHP include on each individual file into a div and show/hide with JS. Set images to lazy load, too, and the browser will take care of them. Still yuck to me, but it works. Generally bad for SEO and possibly a11y, too. Or, rethink the design and make the site extra-vertical, where each links scrolls you. Throw CSS sticky at it for the nav. Each “section” can still be a file. Or continue as is. Your idea isn’t wrong or bad, but you are fighting an uphill battle against the default way the web works.

@ChrisHaas That first option sounds pretty interesting. Could help me learn some more too. I’ll try that out. Thank you so much for your help.

Why do you not use a framework for this? Frameworks handle these problems.

@jabaa I have never used one before. What would you recommend?

Asking for software recommendations is of topic. A quick internet search should point you to popular frameworks. The Wiki also contains a list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application. Don't reinvent the wheel. Learn, how very experienced developers solved all these problems.

@JethroBlemur, because you are learning, I just say go for it. Build and launch v1. Then find the bugs or features you want to implement/change and build and launch v2. Repeat until you are happy, satisfied with your progress or are bored with this. And not to knock frameworks, but I'd recommend staying vanilla in the early stages. Just boring HTML, CSS, JS and HTTP. Whatever framework you are using will ultimately boil down to these under the hood. Once you have a good grasp of these, throw a framework at it (if you want) and see if it makes your life easier.

@ChrisHaas Hmmm, ok that makes sense. I'll have to see what I can do! Thank you once again.

I would recommend exactly the opposite. First, learn best practices and then try to build your own thing, otherwise you will waste much time and perhaps learn bad practices. There is a good reason that we learn science from books and other (smarter) people and not by ourselfs.
